# Check a Liferay portal in Quantcast, Alexa and others

Tags: liferay, meta-tags, static-content

I have a portal in Internet, and I would like to register it in sites like Alexa, Quantcast and other similar sites for ranking and web analyzes.

However, in most of the cases I have to put an HTML file inside the portal, however I do not know how, because all uploaded files are web content in Liferay, and the address is not the address that those sites are going to look for.

In other cases, I have to put an extra meta-data tag, but the only one that I can modify is the keywords meta-tag.

I do not know how to put a file specifically in the portal or add a special meta tag in the head section.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add those in theme of yours. Check out portal-normal.vm to add meta tags in the head section. And you can create a separate footer.vm if you want to include any javascript snippet.